# Print \frac{4}{3} m/s using the SI unit package

Tags: siunitx

How do I print `\frac{4}{3} m/s` using the `siunitx` package?

`$\SI{\frac{4}{3}}{m/s}$` gives an error.

Comment: The  `\num` and `\SI` commands have an optional argument, `$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\frac{4}{3}}{\meter/\second}$`, but `$\frac{4}{3}$ \si{\meter/\second}` could be a better approach

Comment: In addition to Boris' answer, note that it might be better to write `\SI{3/4}{\meter\per\second}`, and have `\sisetup{quotient-mode=fraction,per-mode=symbol}`. If you decide at some point to use units of the form m s^{-1}, then you just need to remove the `per-mode=symbol` from the `\sisetup`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I suggest editing Boris' answer to include this information as it is what I was looking for.

Comment: I am voting to close this as a duplicate of the [question asking about the removal of this functionality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598236/48973) as people reading this question will find the information they need there (even though the question is not _literally_ a duplicate).

Answer (score 25):

SIunitx can output fractions if you (1) tell it to do this, and (2) write down input as a/b:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{quotient-mode=fraction} % Output a/b as \frac{a}{b}
\SI{3/4}{\meter/\second}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can set the quotient mode on a case by case basis:

```
\SI[quotient-mode=fraction]{3/4}{\meter/\second}
```

or change the fraction macro:

```
\SI[quotient-mode=fraction, fraction-function=\dfrac]{3/4}{\meter/\second} 
% Need amsmath for \dfrac
```